# Why is Webpack changing behaviour of javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, aws-lambda

I write my lambda in Typescript which I compile into Javascript using `tsc`. Then, I use Webpack to pack all js files (I don't use Typescript loader of Webpack). Here's my Webpack config:

```js
const glob = require('glob');
const path = require('path');
const _ = require('lodash');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: glob.sync('./apps/aws/**/lambda/*.js').reduce(
    (acc, file) => ({
      ...acc,
      [_.trimEnd(file, '.js')
        .split('/')
        .reduce(
          (acc, chunk, index, array) =>
            index === array.length - 1
              ? [...acc, 'dist', chunk]
              : [...acc, chunk],
          []
        )
        .join('/')]: file
    }),
    {}
  ),
  output: {
    filename: './[name]/index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname),
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  },
  target: 'node',
  externals: ['aws-sdk']
};
```

It worked great for all my lambda until I arrived at this problem:

My new lambda needs to use an external library which asks for a adapter constructor in its config file. It does the following check:

```js
if (!adapter.prototype || !adapter.prototype.constructor.name) {
    throw new Error(
      'Expected "adapter" to be a constructor, provide a valid adapter in Provider config.',
    );
  }
```

It's okay if I provide the constructor in the same config file:

```js
class MyAdapter implements Adapter {
  name: string;

  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

export const configuration: Configuration = {
  adapter: MyAdapter,
  ...
}
```

The above code works if I use Webpack.

My problem starts when I import the adapter into config file:

In another file: `export class MyAdapter implements Adapter {...`
In config file:

```js
import { MyAdapter } from './adapter';

export const configuration: Configuration = {
  adapter: MyAdapter,
  ...
}
```

The above code works in lambda if I don't use Webpack, but when I pack using Webpack, the library throws error: `Expected \"adapter\" to be a constructor, provide a valid adapter in Provider config.`

Why is this happening? How to solve this issue?